# How do I add comments to OpenCart Error log?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

In Laravel, I can use the `log()` command to add comments to the log file (which helps me debug), something like this:

```
$var = 'this is a variable';
//some other code goes here
log::('Is $var a null? Here is the value '.$var);
```

I can then check in the log file.

How do I do this in OpenCart?

Answer (score 6):

In OpenCart 2 and 3 there is log library in */system/library/log.php*

This library is accessible from almost everywhere (from any model and controller). You can easily use it like:

```
$var = 'this is a variable';
//some other code goes here
$this->log->write('Is $var a null? Here is the value '.$var);
```

Log files you will find in */system/storage/logs/error.log*

---

Other way

```
$var = 'this is a variable';
//some other code goes here
$log = new Log('LOG_NAME.log');
$log->write('Is $var a null? Here is the value '.$var);
```

You will find your log file in */system/storage/logs/*